# Eu estou tentando estender StringRequest do pacote volley, mas a importação não está funcionando, por quê?

Tags: java, android, volley

Esse aqui é o código que eu uso pra importar.

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
```

E aqui abaixo tem um print da minha tela mostrando que eu já instalei o pacote volley corretamente.

[image: Print]

Atualização 1:

Atualizei o build.gradle(Module:app) com o código abaixo como sugerido mas o erro persiste!

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' //este não está DEPRECATED
}
```

[image: print2]

Error:Execution failed for task ':android-volley-master:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Smoacademy\android-volley-master\build\intermediates\symbols\androidTest\debug\R.txt (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)

Ainda sem resolução.

Atualização 3:

Problema resolvido após ir em build e clicar em clean project.

Comment: Você confirmou se realmente foi importado a biblioteca do `Volley`?

Comment: Como realizo a confirmação?

Comment: Vá no seu buld.gradle e veja se está usando o `'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' ` o `'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'` já está DEPRECATED e tem algumas classes que não funcionam mais.

Comment: Para mais informações, entre [aqui](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) e veja com mais detalhes.

Comment: O estranho é que fui em todos os build.grade e não tem dizendo a versão se é o mcxiaoke ou o outro.

Comment: Você importou seu projeto do Eclipse?

Comment: Esse link ae que você me mandou é do DEPRECATED. Teria o link do que está funcionando?

Comment: Importei do android studio.

Comment: Justamente! Vou postar como resposta como você tem que fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle? É de comer ou passar no cabelo?

O Android Studio é baseada na IntelliJ IDEA da JetBrains, que tem como uma de suas principais features, e por muitas vezes ignorada, um novo sistema de build muito mais moderno baseado em gradle.

**Gradle** é um sistema de automatização de builds, assim como o Ant e Maven, e pode ser assim definido:

> A combinação do poder e flexibilidade do Ant com o gerenciamento de
>   dependências e convenções do Maven em uma maneira mais eficaz.

Configurar dependências sem precisar importar arquivos .jar ou bibliotecas em código para o projeto é uma das grandes vangagens de usar o gradle no desenvolvimento Android.

No arquivo app/build.gradle você precisa indicar ao build do gradle suas dependências, então adicione as no seu arquivo suas dependências. No seu caso, você precisa adicionar o `volley`.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' //este não está DEPRECATED
}
```

Apenas isso e o gradle se encarrega de baixar as dependências, sem precisar importar bibliotecas para dentro do workspace.

Dê uma lida [aqui](http://adrianolisboa.com/afinal-de-contas-o-que-e-o-gradle-e-como-usa-lo/) neste artigo para mais detalhes.

Comment: Ele sincronizou mas aê apareceu esse erro:
Error:Execution failed for task ':android-volley-master:processDebugResources'.
> Error: A library uses the same package as this project: com.android.volley

Comment: Insira uma imagem do seu build.grade na sua pergunta por favor.

Comment: Encontrei o local correto onde eu coloco esse código e o erro mudou. Agora está pedindo para instalar componentes em falta, estou instalando.

Comment: Pronto! atualizei a pergunta com um novo print.

Comment: e tbm tentei trocar o 21 por 22 que é a versão mais recente do appcompat mas mesmo assim não resolveu.

Comment: Problema resolvido após ir em build e clicar em clean project.

Obg pela ajuda!

Comment: Opa! Que bom!!! Qualquer coisa, dá um grito aqui!!! =) Boa Sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando o Volley oficial do Android? Os outros estão todos obsoletos.

Use esse import aqui, veja se resolve:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Como uso esse import? não entendo bem o que significa esse compile que você colocou ae.

Comment: Você precisa ir no seu arquivo build.gradle dentro do diretório app, e lá nesse arquivo você consegue ver os compiles, inclui essa linha lá

Comment: Inclui mas ainda persiste o erro. Atualizei a pergunta acima com mais um print se quiser dar uma olhada.

Comment: Tenta clicar em Build e em Clean Project, veja se resolve.

Comment: PQP! Né que resolveu mesmo? obg. kkkk

Comment: Quando você ver que ta tudo certo no código e da uns erros estranhos, usa  esse Clean Project, que o Android Studio realoca tudo no seu devido lugar! Que bom que resolveu...kkk

Comment: blza! vlw mesmo hein